# each returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy guys,

I have a table like

```
    <table id="table4">
    <tr>
        <td>Id:</td>
        <td>Nome:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1515</td>
        <td>Thiago</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>Guttierre</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and when my script do...

```
    $("#table4 tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function ai() {
      var d = $(this).text();
      if ((d != 0) && (d != "") && (d != 'undefined') && (d != "Id:")) {
          alert(d);
      };
    });
```

It returns: 1515, then 2015 and then returns an error:

> Microsoft JScript run-time error:"Undefined" is null or isn't an object.

Why it returns "undefined"???

Thks guys!

Comment: You might want to take the quotes off `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior...which version of IE are you getting it in? Also, do you get it with my simple test here? http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/TELtZ/

Comment: I've tried to take off the quotes and didn't worked. But wihout the name "ai" it worked. Why it happens?

Comment: This is called Named Function Expression. Read more on that here: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ It mentions some JScript bugs, but I didn't go into details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named function literals are legal JavaScript, but I believe due to scope issues some browsers may not handle these properly. From [the link that Marko Dumic provided](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs) in his comment:

> Unfortunately, JScript (i.e. Internet Explorer’s ECMAScript implementation) seriously messed up named function expressions.

If you are not going to use the function `ai` anywhere else, try removing the name (oh and as Orbling says, `undefined` is a variable if you are comparing to that "value" so remove the quotes):

```
$("#table4 tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function() {
  var d = $(this).text();
  if ((d != 0) && (d != "") && (d != undefined) && (d != "Id:")) {
      alert(d);
  };
});
```

Comment: @BoltClock: `:)` Note that in modern browsers, `undefined` has been made non-configurable, so it basically behaves as a keyword (like e.g. `null`). Just felt pedantic I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I check your script in chrome.
It works alright.
Remember to wrap this function in

```
$(document).ready()
```

or put it in the body section.